# Neural Network regression on time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, decomposition

I want to predict the trend values of a time serie [Y] based on the effect of other 10 input variables which can also have interaction. Since the combination of interaction between the inputs is unknown, I am applying a regression Neural Network to automatically detect and take that into account. The process I follow is:

**1.** Get raw data of [Y] time serie per day

**2.** Perform decomposition and extract the [Y] Trend element per day

**3.** Merge observations of the [Y] Trend with the observations of the 10 variables by day into a common table

**4**Group the observations by unique combination of x[10] variables and average [Y]  observations by "group_by" combination

**5.** Normalize (min-max) all variables between 0 and 1

**6.** Fit a NN model with:

- Trend as 1 output node
- The 10 variables as the input nodes
- 1 hidden layer
- logistic activation function

**7.** Perform k-fold cross-validation to estimate MAPE error

Am I following a logic approach or is it anything important that I'm missing?

Comment: To me it is fine, take it just as a hint that it may be fine and look at the opinion of the other members, but it should be.. the only thing I don't fully understand is why after de-trending at point 2 you re-insert the trend at point 3 among the variables and normalize it (at least this is what i roughly understood, so maybe I just misinterpreted..)

Comment: Thanks @Fr1! Indeed I had to perform the detrending on an isolated table otherwise the detrend function will run across all the rest variables, including the ones I don't want to detrend.

Comment: @Fri just to clarify :) at 2 I'm keeping the trend hence I'm not detrending but deseasonalizing the time serie.

Comment: ok sorry I likely misinterpreted